# Load resource file from outside of JAR file

Tags: java, maven, jar, shared-libraries

With `maven` I'm building an application which has to load a driver dynamically. With the following code it only works if the `driver.so` is positioned **inside** the resulting *JAR* file. What can I do that the file can be found **outside** of the *JAR* within the path `./natives/driver.so`.

```
package com.myproject;

public class Starter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File classpathRoot = new File(Starter.class.getClassLoader().getResource("driver.so").getPath());
        System.out.println(classpathRoot);
    }
}
```

Output when driver is positioned **inside** *JAR* is:

```
jar:file:/home/ted/java/myproject/target/myproject-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/libgdx64.so
```

Output when positioned **outside** *JAR* (in `target` as well as in `target/natives` directory) is:

```
null
```

I start the application via:

```
cd /home/ted/java/myproject/target/
java -Djava.library.path=./natives -cp myproject-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.myproject.Starter
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package com.myproject;

public class Starter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("natives/driver.so");
        System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```

or this:

```
package com.myproject;

public class Starter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("java.library.path"), "driver.so");
        System.out.println(file);
    }
}
```